# JSON.Stringify overwriting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

JSON.Stringify seems to not work with my objects. My code is this:

```
var LessonTimes={}, CurrentLesson={}, LessonTimeID=1;
$('.AddTimeSection').each(function(e){
    CurrentLesson['day']=$(this).find('.AddTimeDay').val();
    CurrentLesson['start']=$(this).find('.AddTimeStart').val();
    CurrentLesson['end']=$(this).find('.AddTimeEnd').val();
    CurrentLesson['notes']=$(this).find('.AddTimeNotes').val();
    CurrentLesson['id']=LessonTimeID;
    LessonTimes[LessonTimeID]=CurrentLesson;
    console.log(LessonTimes[LessonTimeID]);
    LessonTimeID+=1;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(LessonTimes));
```

And the output of my JSON.stringify is below. As you can see, the last object is repeated, but I cannot figure out why as all the individual objects are correct.

```
Object {day="Mon", start="15:00", end="16:00", id=1, ...}
Object {day="Tue", start="16:00", end="17:00", id=2, ...}
Object {day="Wed", start="17:00", end="18:00", id=3, ...}
JSON = {"1":{"day":"Wed","start":"17:00","end":"18:00","notes":"","id":3},"2":{"day":"Wed","start":"17:00","end":"18:00","notes":"","id":3},"3":{"day":"Wed","start":"17:00","end":"18:00","notes":"","id":3}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with `JSON`.

You need to re-assign `CurrentLesson={}` on each iteration. Otherwise, you're changing the same object.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var LessonTimes = [];
$('.AddTimeSection').each(function(e){
    LessonTimes.push({
        day: $(this).find('.AddTimeDay').val(),
        start: $(this).find('.AddTimeStart').val(),
        end: $(this).find('.AddTimeEnd').val(),
        notes: $(this).find('.AddTimeNotes').val(),
        id: LessonTimes.length
    });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(LessonTimes));
```